# TightVNC Server Not Working at Debian 12 - Grey Screen Appears

Tags: linux, debian, shell, vnc

I have installed TightVNC Server on my system using sudo apt-get install tightvncserver. However, when I try to connect to it, I only get a grey screen. Below are the contents of my ~/.vnc/xstartup file and /etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service file:

Content of ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

Content of /etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=TightVNC server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H:1.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :1
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Despite having configured these files, the VNC server is not functioning and giving only gray screen. How can I resolve this issue and get the TightVNC Server to display the desktop environment properly?